# with 2 separate Wordpress installs, how to achieve a new member signing up on one site and automatically be inserted into the other?

Tags: wordpress

How can this situation be done?

Wordpress install at ABC.com.
Wordpress install at 123.com.

A new member signs up at abc.com, then instantly and automatically, the same user's email address and password be programmatically inserted into 123.com. After the abc.com sign up process is completed, the new user is redirected to log in at 123.com.

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve your functionality using two tricks, firstly you have to connect your wordpress with second DB.

```
global $wpdb;
$newdb = new wpdb( 'USERNAME' , 'PASSWORD' , 'DATABASE NAME' , 'HOST' );
$newdb->show_errors();
```

Then you can use the **user_register** hook to get all data from user upon registration AND update them to new database as a user.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );

function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
   //print_r($_POST); // to get all information of user

   // Insert data in other database
    $newdb->insert('wp_users', array(
       'display_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
       'user_email' => $_POST['user_email'],
       'user_phone' => $_POST['user_phone'], // ... and so on
    ));

}
```

Haven't tried this code but it will work.